# Populate zip code field from url variable using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to figure out how to populate zip code field on form from url variable using jquery/javascript and struggling on how to achieve this. I have a jsfiddle of my code: https://jsfiddle.net/jsavage/Lumxgm92/9/ . I did a similar thing for populating the email address on a form from the url parameter but I can't figure out how to do the same for populating zip code on a form from url parameter. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

```
 <!--- BEGIN POPULATE ZIPCODE FIELD FROM URL VARIABLE CODE --->

  Y.use('jquery-noconflict', function() {

    function getQuerystring(key, default_) {
        if (default_ == null) default_ = "";
        key = key.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
        var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + key + "=([^&#]*)");
        var qs = regex.exec(decodeURIComponent (window.location.href));
        if (qs == null)
            return default_;
        else
            return qs[1];
    }

    var other_value = getQuerystring('zipcode');
    other_value = other_value.replace(/(%[a-zA-Z0-9].)/g, "");
    other_value = other_value.replace(/(\+)/g, "");
    jQuery('#billing_addr_zipname').val(other_value);
});
```

```
    <label for="billing_addr_zipname">ZIPCODE:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billing_addr_zipname" id="billing_addr_zipname" value="" maxlength="50" />
```

Comment: Please specify which step in the process it fails. Do you get a value back from `getQuerystring('zipcode')`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
```

Do this:

```
var zip = <yourzipcode>;
    var lat;
    var lng;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': zip }, function (results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': results[0].geometry.location}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    var loc = getCityState(results);
                }
            }
        });
        }
    }); 

function getCityState(results)
    {
        var a = results[0].address_components;
        var city, state;
        for(i = 0; i <  a.length; ++i)
        {
           var t = a[i].types;
           if(compIsType(t, 'administrative_area_level_1'))
              state = a[i].long_name; //store the state
           else if(compIsType(t, 'locality'))
              city = a[i].long_name; //store the city
        }
        return (city + ', ' + state)
    }

function compIsType(t, s) { 
       for(z = 0; z < t.length; ++z) 
          if(t[z] == s)
             return true;
       return false;
    }
```

This all returns a string containing the city and state, but you can adjust this to your needs.

Answer (score -1):

What is that regex supposed to be doing? It looks like it just replaces all the alphanumerics in your retrieved value with "".

EDIT:

Scratch that. It replaces escaped html chars like %20.

Comment: Should have been a comment in the first place